# Error Brew unable to install NGINX when run Laravel install

Tags: nginx, homebrew

i want to install Laravel Valet throught my Mac but i got error when run `laravel install`. I did all the steps from laravel official about valet but when i run `laravel install`. i got this error.

```
Installing nginx...
[nginx] is not installed, installing it now via Brew... 
==> Downloading https://ghcr.io/v2/homebrew/core/nginx/manifests/1.23.0
Already downloaded: /Users/ferdinandgushcloud/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/538475811e1d9f1d3d3b11ac2bc827bae97e4e11b14a5033fd31abeafffcf28e--nginx-1.23.0.bottle_manifest.json
==> Downloading https://ghcr.io/v2/homebrew/core/nginx/blobs/sha256:c697d19eb4e0fcb55f8cf48f27f92a778608b7fa9409216e5bd13b52bcb8746c
curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 401 
Error: nginx: Failed to download resource "nginx"
Download failed: https://ghcr.io/v2/homebrew/core/nginx/blobs/sha256:c697d19eb4e0fcb55f8cf48f27f92a778608b7fa9409216e5bd13b52bcb8746c


In Brew.php line 168:
                                       
  Brew was unable to install [nginx].  
                                       

install
```

i tried many posibility to fix it but still not to fix it. this is what i've done

1. I run commend `brew update`  then run `brew install nginx`. but i got this error

```
==> Downloading https://ghcr.io/v2/homebrew/core/nginx/manifests/1.23.0
Already downloaded: /Users/ferdinandgushcloud/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/538475811e1d9f1d3d3b11ac2bc827bae97e4e11b14a5033fd31abeafffcf28e--nginx-1.23.0.bottle_manifest.json
==> Downloading https://ghcr.io/v2/homebrew/core/nginx/blobs/sha256:c697d19eb4e0fcb55f8cf48f27f92a778608b7fa94092
##O#- #                                                                       
curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 401 
Error: nginx: Failed to download resource "nginx"
Download failed: https://ghcr.io/v2/homebrew/core/nginx/blobs/sha256:c697d19eb4e0fcb55f8cf48f27f92a778608b7fa9409216e5bd13b52bcb8746c
```

2. run command `brew install nginx --hack`. but got this error

```
Error: invalid option: --hack
```

3. run command `brew services restart --all`. display this

```
==> Successfully started `php` (label: homebrew.mxcl.php)
==> Successfully started `php@7.4` (label: homebrew.mxcl.php@7.4)
==> Successfully started `redis` (label: homebrew.mxcl.redis)
```

then i run commend `valet install` but the error still same

4. run command `brew postinstall nginx`. display this error

```
==> Postinstalling nginx
Warning: The post-install step did not complete successfully
You can try again using:
  brew postinstall nginx
```

5. run command `rm -r ~/.config/valet`.  then i run commend `valet install` but the error still same

please help. I need to use valet for my laravel project

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. really Easy just run `sudo valet install` we need to add `sudo` and run this as super user and this is the result

```
Installing nginx...
[nginx] is not installed, installing it now via Brew... 
Installing nginx configuration...
Installing nginx directory...
Installing and configuring phpfpm...
Updating PHP configuration for php@8.1...
Restarting php...
Installing dnsmasq...
[dnsmasq] is not installed, installing it now via Brew... 
Updating Dnsmasq configuration...
Restarting dnsmasq...
Valet is configured to serve for TLD [.test]
Restarting nginx...
```